# Is the UML architecture clean and specific enough to be coded in java

Tags: java, uml, dry

I've learned the UML recently and I am trying to build a `MonsterDuel` system. However, there are a lot of classes in this project, and I am confused about the abstract class and its usage. Now, I have created:

1. Abstract class `Players`, and its inherited class `Player`.
2. Abstract class `Field`
3. The multiple card classes associated with each other.

Apart from the getter and the setter, is this structure clean and specific enough to proceed on java coding?
And, if it's not, what can I improve?

Any opinion or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you for your time and patience.

[image: Monster Duel System]

Comment: Chances are high this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try it on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). But before posting, improve your question by actually explaining the design. Noone is going to try find out everything by himself just by looking at the UML.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. It's the first time I post this kind of question, don't know how and where to ask. I'll add the explanation next time. @akuzminykh

Comment: You might want to review your UML book as you seem to have gotten some of the concepts wrong (abstract classes, generalization)

Comment: Thank you for reviewing. I will keep trying. @GeertBellekens

Answer (score 1):

I would start with what you have there. 
You can generate the Class stubs and then stat filling them with the logic.

In general I would do increments. Between implementing and updating the Diagram. UML is a good tool for helping you visualizing where your code is going and find out if something is moving into the wrong way.

I never had an project where the UML was super detailed and the code was in the end representing it.

So as a short answer: Yes this is good enough, but do iterations and revisit and adapt.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my UML diagram. So, the next step for me is to implement the UML to java code and see if anything goes wrong, right?  @Corso